# Error with UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python, unicode, ascii, non-ascii-characters

I get this error when i try to run my jabber bot.

```
  File "modules/xmpp/dispatcher.py", line 16, in Process
    self.Stream.Parse(data)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xc5 in position 32: invalid continuation byte
```

The error is in line 143 in this code:

```
def Process(self, timeout=0):
    """ Check incoming stream for data waiting. If "timeout" is positive - block for as max. this time.
        Returns:
        1) length of processed data if some data were processed;
        2) '0' string if no data were processed but link is alive;
        3) 0 (zero) if underlying connection is closed.
        Take note that in case of disconnection detect during Process() call
        disconnect handlers are called automatically.
    """
    for handler in self._cycleHandlers: handler(self)
    if len(self._pendingExceptions) > 0:
        _pendingException = self._pendingExceptions.pop()
        raise _pendingException[0], _pendingException[1], _pendingException[2]
    if self._owner.Connection.pending_data(timeout):
        try: data=self._owner.Connection.receive()
        except IOError: return
        self.Stream.Parse(data)
        if len(self._pendingExceptions) > 0:
            _pendingException = self._pendingExceptions.pop()
            raise _pendingException[0], _pendingException[1], _pendingException[2]
        if data: return len(data)
    return '0'      # It means that nothing is received but link is alive.
```

it need to decode the `data` string in line 16 or what?

please hack the code and solve my problem..

Comment: Which line here is line 143?

Comment: What is `self.Stream` here?

Comment: And when the exception occurs, what does `repr(data)` look like? Use `try: self.Stream.Parse(data)`, `except UnicodeDecodeError: print(repr(data))` to find out.

Comment: all code is here: `http://qfs.mobi/f1485283` the problem is in `line 143`

Answer (score 0):

I would try `self.Stream.Parse(data.encode('utf-8'))` instead and see if that works.

Comment: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd8 in position 163: ordinal not in range(128)`

Comment: how about `self.Stream.Parse(data.decode(locale.getpreferredencoding()).encode('utf-8'))`

Comment: It appears `data` is ASCII encoded, but `self.Stream.Parse` is expecting UTF-8 data. So I see you can handle this in one of 2 ways:

1) Modify the self.Stream object to support ASCII data. Or...
2) Make sure that the data going into self.Stream.Parse is UTF-8 encoded

Comment: I get problem when i use `self.Stream.Parse(data.decode(locale.getpreferredencoding()).encode('utf-8')` The problem is: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xd8 in position 3994: unexpected end of data`

Comment: The id which i run it on this file have about 1700 users. Because i have run onther id in the same bot file and its working as well. To know the second bot id have just 1200 users. meby the problem because the id which i run the file on it has alot of users..!!

Comment: The problem then is with the data coming in, not the code. Can you provide a pcap sample of the packet(s) it gets?

Comment: Also, the server may be sending the data in chunks (multiple packets) which may mean you may have to call `Connect.Receive()` multiple times to make sure you have to combine the data in the packets before passing it to Stream.Parse.

You may have to parse the header to get the length of the UTF-8 payload, and track the length as you read in the multiple packets.

Comment: Bot receive presence from diffrent ids type. English, arabic ids i think the problem because the bot receive alot of presence eace of this presence has different type of id. see bot config file `http://qfs.mobi/f1485805`

Comment: The problem now is the bot dont uincode the data before passing it to Stream..?